# Does Akka Streams Unzip/Zip preserve order?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

If I unzip a series of tuples, perform some asynchronous mutations on the two streams, and then re-zip them, does Akka guarantee the streams are re-zipped in the same order?

Example:

```scala
import akka.NotUsed
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.{ActorMaterializer, FlowShape}
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Flow, GraphDSL, Sink, Source, Unzip, Zip}

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}

val graph: Flow[(Int, String), (Int, String), NotUsed] = Flow.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._

  val unzip = builder.add(Unzip[Int, String])
  val increment = builder.add(Flow[Int].mapAsync(3) { num => Future(num + 1) })
  val append = builder.add(Flow[String].mapAsync(3) { letter => Future(s"$letter-x") })
  val zip = builder.add(Zip[Int, String])

  unzip.out0 ~> increment ~> zip.in0
  unzip.out1 ~> append ~> zip.in1

  FlowShape(unzip.in, zip.out)
})

implicit val system = ActorSystem()
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

val out = Source(collection.immutable.Seq((0, "a"), (1, "b"), (2, "c")))
  .via(graph)
  .runWith(Sink.seq)

Await.result(out, 1 second)
```

In this simple test, the output is `Vector((1,a-x), (2,b-x), (3,c-x))`. So things are looking good. But I'm not sure I can trust this will always be the case.

Something which raises a bit of concern is this:

```scala
val unzip = builder.add(Unzip[Int, String])
val increment = builder.add(Flow[Int].mapAsync(3) { num => Future(num + 1) })
val filter = builder.add(Flow[Int].filter(_ != 2))
val append = builder.add(Flow[String].mapAsync(3) { letter => Future(s"$letter-x") })
val zip = builder.add(Zip[Int, String])

unzip.out0 ~> increment ~> filter ~> zip.in0
unzip.out1 ~> append ~> zip.in1

// output: Vector((1,a-x), (3,b-x))
```

Even if the ordering is preserved, there's no guarantee the original tuple relationship will be preserved.

I can manually inspect my flows to make sure there's no filtering logic. But with that done, can I be sure the tuples will be re-zipped in precisely the order they were received?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR yes, it does. From [Stream ordering](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-flows-and-basics.html#stream-ordering) docs in Akka:

> In Akka Streams almost all computation operators preserve input order of elements. This means that if inputs `{IA1,IA2,...,IAn}` “cause” outputs `{OA1,OA2,...,OAk}` and inputs `{IB1,IB2,...,IBm}` “cause” outputs `{OB1,OB2,...,OBl}` and all of `IAi` happened before all `IBi` then `OAi` happens before `OBi`.
>
> This property is even upheld by `async` operations such as `mapAsync`, however an unordered version exists called `mapAsyncUnordered` which does not preserve this ordering.
>
> However, in the case of Junctions which handle multiple input streams (e.g. `Merge`) the output order is, in general, not defined for elements arriving on different input ports. That is a merge-like operation may emit `Ai` before emitting `Bi`, and it is up to its internal logic to decide the order of emitted elements. **Specialized elements such as `Zip` however do guarantee their outputs order, as each output element depends on all upstream elements having been signalled already – thus the ordering in the case of zipping is defined by this property.**
>
> If you find yourself in need of fine grained control over order of emitted elements in fan-in scenarios consider using `MergePreferred`, `MergePrioritized` or `GraphStage` – which gives you full control over how the merge is performed.

Comment: Sweet. I also found a [PassThrough flow](https://gist.github.com/davideicardi/d3b383e5945a44252931582f83ecadc2) example which supports this conclusion. Thanks!